# Bash script template to copy files to predefined destination folders

Tags: linux, rsync, bash-scripting

I need an interactive bash script template to copy files to predefined destination folders. If possible, when prompted for user input tab completion would be enabled for a predefined source directory. The basic logic would go something like this:

script example 1:

```
/bin/bash    
enable tab completion to load from /src/dir #perhaps using pwd as script is loaded    
echo "filename or pattern?" #interactively ask user to provide filename or pattern    
'user input'=$FILENAME #define interactive user input as filename    
rsync -rv /src/dir/$FILENAME /dest/dir/ && rm -r /src/dir/$FILENAME    
done
```

I know it's rough/incorrect but hopefully the desired outcome is clear enough. Thanks in advance for any guidance!! Links to specific bash scripting techniques would be much appreciated.

I tried this (thanks for the help [Noam N. Kremen](https://superuser.com/users/97441/noam-n-kremen) and [slhk](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)!!!):

```
#!/bin/bash  
read -e -p "Filename or pattern? " SRC_FILE  
rsync "$SRC_FILE" /dest/dir && rm -r "$SRC_FILE"
```

So, tab completion works great, and after "quoting" the strings

```
"$SRC_FILE"
```

rsync stopped throwing errors. Looks like I now have a great little script doing EXACTLY what I need it to!! And I learned how to format code correctly on here, Thanks!!

Comment: Please indent code by 4 spaces. What file are you copying? Does it contain a space in its name or path? Try quoting `rsync "$SRC_FILE"`, and see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Thank you very much sir, problem fixed, and looking forward to perusing your site for more tips.

Comment: No problem. I think at this point you should accept Noam's answer below, by clicking the green checkmark next to it, as he helped you figure out the solution. And welcome to Super User, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `read -e -p` as in:

```
read -e -p "Enter destination filename" DEST_FILE
```

-e enables autocompletion and $DEST_FILE will hold the data you need.

Comment: Fantastic and quick help, thank you my friend!